Physical basis of "forced harmonics" on a violin
I have recently learnt of a somewhat novel violin technique, sometimes known as "forced harmonics", where, in a physicist's terms, instead of the normal N=1 stationary wave (fundamental mode) being produced normally on a violin, the it can be somewhat suppressed and the $n=2$ wave (first overtone) can be produced cleanly. This is not the usual technique of (natural/artificial) harmonics where a finger is placed on the nodes of the $n=2/3/4$ wave to induce those waves. Instead, no fingers are placed on the node of the $n=2$ wave; the first overtone is solely produced by a combination of finger pressure on the note, as well as bow pressure and position.
Below is the description from the "inventor" of the technique:

Practice placing light pressure on the string with the left hand!
The bow must lie at a particular point on the string. The best way to begin is by finding this point on the fingerboard, far from the bridge. Play with great bow speed and practice using very light pressure from the bow. The effect causes the note to sound an octave higher with a color similar to standard harmonic.
Later, to produce a more forceful tone, you can increase the bow pressure and place the bow  closer to the bridge.
Each 'Harmonic' is bowed at a different point on the string: the higher the pitch, the closer to the bridge you must bow.

(Source)
There are also some videos of the inventor of the technique demonstraing its use, e.g. this video starting at 4:19 (notice how his fingers didn't move but the notes switch between the normal notes (i.e. the fundamental mode) and notes that are an octave higher (i.e. the first overtone).
What is the physical basis of this technique? And why is the fundamental mode suppressed? I understand that violin playing is generally described by the Helmholtz motion, but I have never read about a theoretical analysis involving a semi-fixed end (in the form of a lightly pressed string) and the suppression of the fundamental mode under certain conditions.

This is called ''pinch harmonics'' or ''artificial harmonics'' and has been used by guitar players (probably players of all stringed instruments) for a long time.

@Tom I also expect that it's related to pinch harmonics, but it seems slightly different. My guess is that the bowing technique is somehow suppressing the fundamental antinode, but I'm not quite sure what's going on. I'm a guitarist, not a violinist.

Some thoughts:
The specification for the left hand: 'light pressure on the string'.
Is that violonist jargon? That is: in this context, in what way is 'light pressure' different from 'normal pressure'?
My best guess is that the instruction 'light pressure' is to be understood as: instead of bringing the string all the way to the fingerboard only touch the string at the point where you would otherwise press the string all the way to the fingerboard. That would tend to correspond to how a slide guitar is played.
But it could also mean: press onto the fingerboard, but use less pressure than normal, so that your fingertip is deformed less than normal.
Either way, for this one it is not clear to see how it makes a difference.

Placement of the bow:
The placement of the bow has an effect on how the energy that the bow transfers to the string ends up distributed over the harmonics of the string.
For instance, if the bow is placed halfway along the length of the string a comparatively large proportion of the energy goes to the fundamental harmonic, since the antinode of the fundamental is halfway along the string.
Placing the bow at 1/4th along the length of the string will tend to shift the transfer of energy towards the second harmonic (N=2 oscillation).

Speed of bowing:
I notice the emphasis that Roman Kim places on speed of bowing.
As you know: there is the stick-slip mechanism. It would appear that a fast speed of bowing favors that there are two cycles of the string oscillation for every cycle of stick-slip.
If that is the case then a higher speed of bowing will favor energizing higher harmonics.
Further reading:
Joe Wolfe, University of New South Wales, Sydney, Australia
Bows and strings

"press onto the fingerboard, but use less pressure than normal, so that your fingertip is deformed less than normal." is the correct interpretation of light pressure. The other description you mentioned about touching the string is more for normal natural/artificial harmonics

for the bow position, the end of the fingerboard to the bridge is roughly at 1/6 of the string's fundamental wavelength, and that's pretty much the range you can bow upon, so I don't think bowing at 1/2 or 1/4 positions are relevant

@musician115 What determines the range (along the length of the string) where you can bow? Of course the 4 strings of a violin are not in the same plane, as with a standard guitar design, so the outer strings are less accessible. But I would expect the two middle strings to be quite accessible to bowing.

I think it's not about the accessibility of string bowing. In violin, bowing as close as possible to the bridge (fixed end) generally gives a "richer" tone with more overtones, and nearer the fingerboard (around 1/6) gives a flatter tone with less overtones. Anywhere further and even the fundamental frequency becomes too weak.

@musician115 Sure, for regular playing you stay close to the bridge. But this isn't regular playing. This is a special move, a single stroke at a time. Roman Kim writes: 'The best way to begin is by finding this point on the fingerboard, far from the bridge.'
(Incidentally, my background is singing. For singing having a physics background is quite beneficial.)

Forced harmonics happen more commonly with a lightly depressed string (more than for a harmonic and less than for a true note). Bowing anywhere near the 1/4 point of the string is absurd and not required. A faster bow goes nowhere to explaining the phenomenon.
